# Why I get an error message when using spherical in MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I wanna find the nearest point of [2, 2.01], I typed query sentence as below, but, it gave me an error message : invalid argument in geo near query: spherical, detail information can be found below

```
> db.places.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5892a41f8c4ec25d8bf6bc61"), "log" : [ 2, 2 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5892a4298c4ec25d8bf6bc62"), "log" : [ 4, 2 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5892a43a8c4ec25d8bf6bc63"), "log" : [ 1, 1 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5892a4448c4ec25d8bf6bc64"), "log" : [ 2, 5 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5892a44f8c4ec25d8bf6bc65"), "log" : [ -20, 23 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5892a45f8c4ec25d8bf6bc66"), "log" : [ 40.757699, -73.987632 ] }
> db.place.find( { log:
... { $near : { $geometry : 
...               { type: "Point", coordinates : [2, 2.01]},
...               spherical : true
...           }
... }})
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "invalid argument in geo near query: spherical",
    "code" : 2,
    "codeName" : "BadValue"
}
```

Comment: `spherical` option is on `$geoNear` and not on `$geometry`

Comment: Hi Sidgate, thank you for your reply, I changed $geometry to $geoNear, however, I got Error again, it said: errmsg:  "invalid argument in geo near query: $geoNear". So I am thinking maybe I wrongly used spherical

Answer (score 0):

consider using mongoose

```
 let memos = await Memo.find({})
        .where('loc')
        .near({
          center: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [parseFloat(lng), parseFloat(lat)],
            spherical: true,
            maxDistance: 2
          }
        })
        .select('img loc')
        .limit(30)
```